How to mix audio data input from microphone with custom PCM data in Windows?
How to mix an audio data into an input stream, coming from a microphone in Windows without a virtual device or a custom driver, using WASAPI or similar API within Windows?

You could try to use Loopback Recording.In loopback mode, a client of WASAPI can capture the audio stream that is being played by a rendering endpoint device. You could modify RecordAudioStream function in   Capturing a Stream to configure a loopback-mode capture stream.
For more details, you could refer to the Blog:Sample - WASAPI loopback capture (record what you hear)

I think, this solution does the opposite. I need to insert my audio data into input stream, while the loopback functionality is intended to capture system output currently being played, am I right?

A microphone is an audio input device that can only produce audio signals/data, but cannot receive them. If you want to mix the audio data, you need to use Loopback Recording.
If you want to take control of the input stream from a microphone in windows, you need to create a virtual audio devices and then have the target program use that.
